# Is the a bug in function save_weights/load_weights with custom layer in tensorflow 1.13.1?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

It took me more than a day, so frustrated. I doubt this is a bug in `Tensorflow 1.13.1` (a stable version).

In summary, I created a custom model in Model Subclassing style, which contained only 1 custom layer. After initial, I dumped its trainable weights to file and restore it, by using save_weights and load_weights functions. The trainable weights before and after saving were different.

I also ran the same test on `Tensorflow 2.0.0a0`, and it turned out this version did not get this phenomenon.

My custom layer:

```
class EncodingLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, out_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.rnn_layer = tf.keras.layers.GRU(out_size, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')

    def call(self, X, **kwargs):
        output, state = self.rnn_layer(X)
        return output, state
```

This is the main part:

```
class EncodingModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder_layer = EncodingLayer(out_size=1)

    def infer(self, inputs):
        output, state = self.encoder_layer(inputs)
        return output


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Comment line below for running in TF 2.0
    tf.enable_eager_execution()

    # shape == (2, 3, 2)
    inputs = tf.convert_to_tensor([
        [[1., 2.], [2., 3.], [4., 4.]],
        [[1., 2.], [2., 3.], [4., 4.]],
    ])

    model = EncodingModel()

    # Just for building the graph
    model.infer(inputs)

    print('Before saving model: ', model.trainable_weights[0].numpy().mean())
    model.save_weights('weight')

    new_model = EncodingModel()
    new_model.infer(inputs)
    new_model.load_weights('weight')
    print('Loaded model: ', new_model.trainable_weights[0].numpy().mean())
```

The result when running in TF 1.13.1:

```
Before saving model:  0.28864467
Loaded model:  0.117300846
```

The result when running in TF 2.0.0a0:

```
Before saving model:  -0.06922924
Loaded model:  -0.06922924
```

Although the result suggests that it might be a bug, I was not so sure. Since the code is very basic, if a bug like that exists, it should be discovered easily. I did a lot of searching but found no one mentioning about it. Thus, I'd guess there's something I misunderstood :)